# Вызов функции вида func(x)(x)(x)(x)

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, недавно наткнулся на функцию, которая вызывается следующим способом.

```
func(1)(2)(3)(4)(5);
```

Код самой функции мне недоступен.

В чем смысл подобного вызова функции?

Пытался искать в интернете, но ничего подобного не нашел.

Comment: _В чем смысл подобного вызова функции?_ - в частичном применении, когда можно сначала три раза вызвать функцию, потом, если надо - еще несколько раз.

Comment: Просто `func(1)` возвращает функцию, типа такого: `return function(){// кодик}`. А когда она возвращает её, то сразу же выполняется следующий вызов через `(2)`. И так далее... :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Приведу пример такой функции:

```js
const sum = function(a) {
  var result = a;                              // Первый вызов, инициализация
  const innersum = a => (result+=a, innersum); // Функция возвращает себя же
  innersum.toString = () => result;            // сериализация значения для вывода
  return innersum;
};

console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)(4)); // 10
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3));    // 6

let tmp = sum(2)(3);
console.log(tmp);     // 5
console.log(tmp(5));  //10
console.log(tmp(10)); //20
```

Перевод функции(без "новых стандартов языка"):

```
function sum(a) {
  var result = a;

  function innerSum(a) {
    result += a;
    return innerSum;
  }

  innerSum.toString = function() {
    return result;
  };

  return innerSum;
}
```

Comment: Опять усложняешь?

Comment: @VostokSisters, чего? Можно более конструктивный комментарий получить?

Comment: Нельзя) Просто по сравнению с ответом Qwertiy, по твоему можно докторскую писать. Если у человека такие вопросы, а ты тут новые стандарты языка используешь и всё такое.

Comment: У @Qwertiy слишком уж немногословный ответ. Никакого пояснения. Не люблю такие :(

Comment: @VostokSisters зато не страдает описанным ТС недостатком у ответа Qwertiy.

Comment: @D-side, а, это в комментах он написал. Я не заметил, прочел только вопрос.

Comment: Ответ настолько хорош, насколько сложен. До вашего ответа не знал о стрелочных функциях в JS, пришлось гуглить.

Comment: Увидел поправку, спасибо большое!

Comment: @SlavaPodolskiy, учиться никогда не бывает плохо. Я добавил перевод  на es5, чтобы было понятнее

Comment: @SlavaPodolskiy, в ответе отвечающий уже дополнил пример и без них)

Comment: Я тут тоже ES6 вспомнил и ещё один ответ запостил :)

Comment: @D-side, это не недостаток. Я хотел дать простой понятный ответ, на случай, если непонятен сам принцип. А если нужно именно произвольное число вызовов, то есть этот ответ и мой второй ответ с классом.

Comment: @Qwertiy а почему не редактировал предыдущий? в чем подвох?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, потому что я считаю, что принципиально разные решения должны быть в разных ответах.

Answer (score 5):

```js
function func(a) {
  return function (b) {
    return function (c) {
      return function (d) {
        return function (e) {
          console.log('Ну вот ты и вызвал все 5 функций')
          console.log([a, b, c, d, e].join(' '))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

func(1)(2)(3)(4)(5);
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что количество аргументов заранее неизвестно, то есть может быть и func(1)(2)...(100);

Comment: Тогда тебе уже @vp_arth написал пример.

Answer (score 2):

О, я вспомнил ES6 :)

Некоторые [детали](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517424/178988).

```js
class Summator extends Function {
  constructor() {
    super('return arguments.callee.apply(this, arguments)');
    this.value = 0;
  }

  apply(me, [x]) {
    this.value += x;
    return this;
  }

  toString() {
    return this.value;
  }
}

var func = new Summator(); // Инстанс хранит значение
console.log(func(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)); // 15
// Если использовать существующий инстанс вместо создания нового
console.log(func(1)(2)(3)); // то будет 15+1+2+3 = 21
```

И вариант с неизменяемыми функциями:

```js
class Summator extends Function {
  constructor(x) {
    super('return arguments.callee.apply(this, arguments)');
    this.value = x || 0;
  }

  apply(me, [x]) {
    return new Summator(this.value + x);
  }

  toString() {
    return this.value;
  }
}

function func(x) { // Просто обёртка, чтобы выкинуть new
  return new Summator(x);
}

console.log(func(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)); // 15
console.log(func(1)(2)(3)); // 6
```

Comment: es6 в совокупности с `new Function(string)` страшное зрелище)

Comment: Жесть, но любопытно.

Comment: @vp_arth, а там по-другому нельзя - я уже добавил в ответ ссылку на соответствующий вопрос. А так, замечу, что строка в вызове `super` одинакова для всех наследников, а реальный код помещён в `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

Если без углубления в код JS, то схема такая:

func(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) эквивалентно поочередному вызову цепочки функций, где каждой новой задаются по очереди аргументы 1, 2, 3, 4 и 5 соответственно. важно(!) чтобы каждый вызов функции возвращал (давал в результате) какую-то функцию, чтобы к ней применялся следующий аргумент, кроме последнего вызова с аргументом 5, тут необязательно, чтобы результатом была функция.

func(1) дает функцию func_2, к которой применяем аргумент 2, т.е. func_2(2), это дает в свою очередь func_3 и она вызывается как func_3(3), затем func_4 с вызовом func_4(4) и наконец func_5 с вызовом func_5(5).

Answer (score -1):

Скорее всего, функция `func` возвращает функцию, которая возвращает функцию, которая возвращает функцию и т.д. Нужно это для [каррирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).