# Как понимать вызов функции в JS с двумя скобками: fn()()?

Tags: javascript

[image: функция JS]

Не пойму как тут вызывается функция.

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вызов функции вида func(x)(x)(x)(x)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/642902/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0-funcxxxx)

Comment: @wololo не совсем то

Answer (score 0):

Функция `fn` при вызове возвращает другую, безымянную функцию - вот ее-то и запускают "вторые скобки".

Смотри аналог этого действа - так будет понятнее?

```js
const test = fn()
test(true)

function fn() {
  console.log('Привет из fn')
  return function(prm){
    console.log(prm)
  }
}
```